# If & ifelse condition not working

Tags: php

Trying to execute some code using ifelse method but it is not working!

Tried this [code](https://ideone.com/9p7RrE)

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$cdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$scdate = strtotime($cdate);
$um = 1511643600;
$war = $um - 180;
$pre = $um - 3600;
if($um <= $scdate){
?>
Hello
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: post your code here.

Comment: There is no `if.. else` in the question...

Comment: Please don't use external links. Instead, share a [mcve] here.

Comment: @Akintunde SO is not accepting the question if I paste my code here...

Comment: Seeing you're logged in. can you answer to the [comment I left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486939/how-to-define-php-variable-as-json-value#comment81929790_47486939) in your other question, svp? I haven't seen it updated (yet).

Comment: @PB Musics: The above code uses a meta tag in the body, which is not valid code.

Comment: @Mureinik Updated question

Comment: It works, it would enter an `else` if you had it, https://3v4l.org/2kBYT. Also you don't need the `date` or `strtotime` functions, just use the `time`.

Comment: @chris85 it is not working for me https://3v4l.org/cYK1H

Comment: You only have elseifs, none of your conditions are met. Output the values and see what you have

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good that you already added code to your question, but it is still very unclear what your question really is. Saying that code is or is not working doesn't mean much unless you specify the desired outcome. Code can only work or not work in relation to some expected result. Try to make an effort explaining what you are actually trying to achieve with your code. And if you get an error, include the error message in the question.